# How to get objects by searching the array content

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this object

```
let obj = [
   {name: 'title 1', values:['test 1', 'test 2']},
   {name: 'title 2' values: ['test 3', 'test 4']}
]
```

I want to search for values = 'test 3' and it will return objects contaning that skills
ouput: `{name: 'title 2' values: ['test 3', 'test 4']}`

I have tried searching like `obj.find(c=> c.skills)`, iteration etc. but it only works not inside the array of objects.

Comment: do you want an array of objects or a single object?

Comment: Is your question answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use filer to apply a condition on `values`:

```js
 let obj = [
   {name: 'title 1', values:['test 1', 'test 2']},
   {name: 'title 2', values: ['test 3', 'test 4']}
];

const result = obj.filter(o => o.values.includes('test 3'));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could find the object by looking into the array with [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```js
const
    objects = [{ name: 'title 1', values: ['test 1', 'test 2'] }, { name: 'title 2', values: ['test 3', 'test 4'] }],
    value = 'test 3',
    result = objects.find(({ values }) => values.includes(value));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This will only return the first match.

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter`:

```js
let obj = [{
  name: 'title 1',
  values: ['test 1', 'test 2']
}, {
  name: 'title 2',
  values: ['test 3', 'test 4']
}];

let skill = 'test 3';
let result = obj.filter(c => c.values.includes(skill));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

[`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) should do it.

```js
let obj = [
   {name: 'title 1', values:['test 1', 'test 2']},
   {name: 'title 2', values: ['test 3', 'test 4']}
];
    
    let ans = obj.filter(x => x.values.indexOf('test 3') > -1);
    console.log(ans);
```

Answer (score 0):

`filter` with `includes` already done. `find` with `includes` already done. Then i show the `forEach` version today ;-)

```js
obj = [{
  name: 'title 1',
  values: ['test 1', 'test 2']
}, {
  name: 'title 2',
  values: ['test 3', 'test 4']
}];

n = []
obj.forEach(c => {
  if (c.values.includes('test 3')) {
    n.push(c)
  }
})

console.log('new', n)
```